# Mostrar un campo con el total de una FILA SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente tengo una consulta que resume un conjuto de datos y los agrupa de la siguiente manera

[Resultado de la consulta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfxUv.png)

Para llegar a eso ocupo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT   *
    FROM (
    SELECT T4.nombre AS Cargo, T4.CupoEndeudamientoMensual , T0.fecha,
    REPLACE (RTRIM(T3.nombre),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.NOMBRE1),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO1),'','') as Nombre,
    T1.codbodega,
    CASE WHEN T0.codtipodcto='NC' THEN
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad)*-1,2)
    ELSE
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad),2)
    END AS 'Neto'
    FROM tblencfacturas T0  INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas  T1 ON T1.consecutivo=T0.consecutivo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN dbo.tbltarifas_iva     T2 ON T1.codiva=T2.codiva     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN dbo.tblsocio_negocios  T3 ON T3.codigo=T0.CODIGO     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN dbo.tblgrupos_terceros T4 ON T4.codgrupo = T3.codgrupo
    WHERE T3.ESEMPLEADO='TRUE'  AND T0.CODTIPODCTO IN ('FA','NC') AND  YEAR(T0.fecha)=2020  AND MONTH(T0.fecha)=01 AND (day(T0.fecha)>=02 AND day(T0.fecha)<=16)  AND T0.codigo='E-1001468512'
    ) AS F0
    GROUP BY F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Neto,F0.Cargo, F0.fecha,  F0.Nombre, F0.codbodega
```

Ahora, lo que pretendo hacer es lo siguiente

añadir un campo adicional donde me muestre el total de toda la columna llamada **Neto**

[Ver resultado esperado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESqNR.png)

que seria sumar todos los registros de la columna Neto y poner el total  al lado, como lo muestra la imagen.

ó ¿Cómo mas podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Sin entrar a valorar tu query, puedes envolverla en una tabla derivada y utilizar Sum con OVER.

```
SELECT RESULT.*, SUM(NETO) OVER(ORDER BY NETO DESC) AS TOTAL 
FROM (
SELECT   F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Neto,F0.Cargo, F0.fecha,  F0.Nombre,  F0.codbodega
    FROM (
    SELECT T4.nombre AS Cargo, T4.CupoEndeudamientoMensual , T0.fecha,
    REPLACE (RTRIM(T3.nombre),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.NOMBRE1),'','')+'    '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO),'','')+' '+REPLACE(RTRIM(T3.APELLIDO1),'','') as Nombre,
    T1.codbodega,
    CASE WHEN T0.codtipodcto='NC' THEN
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor *   T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad)*-1,2)
    ELSE
    ROUND((((T1.valor-((T1.valor * T1.descuento)/100))+(((T1.valor-((T1.valor *  T1.descuento)/100)) * T2.porcentaje)/100))*t1.cantidad),2) 
     END AS 'Neto'
    FROM tblencfacturas T0  INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas  T1 ON   T1.consecutivo=T0.consecutivo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN dbo.tbltarifas_iva     T2 ON T1.codiva=T2.codiva     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN dbo.tblsocio_negocios  T3 ON T3.codigo=T0.CODIGO     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
                            INNER JOIN dbo.tblgrupos_terceros T4 ON T4.codgrupo = T3.codgrupo
    WHERE T3.ESEMPLEADO='TRUE'  AND T0.CODTIPODCTO IN ('FA','NC') AND   YEAR(T0.fecha)=2020  AND MONTH(T0.fecha)=01 AND (day(T0.fecha)>=02 AND day(T0.fecha)<=16)    AND T0.codigo='E-1001468512'
    ) AS F0
    GROUP BY F0.CupoEndeudamientoMensual,F0.Neto,F0.Cargo, F0.fecha,  F0.Nombre,    F0.codbodega
) AS RESULT
```

Normalmente la omisión de valores, para que se muestren en blanco, se realiza en el código cliente.

Espero te ayude

Comment: Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de analizar y responder, estare realizando las pruebas correspondientes.